# Is there a better way to get Left-Alt key events than using WM_SYSKEYDOWN?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, callback, keyboard-events

I'm writing a game using C++, to get input on Windows I created Window and Callback.

Everything is working 100% fine and nice, but there is one thing that annoys me.

`WM_KEYDOWN` / `WM_KEYUP` messages are not working for <kbd>Left-Alt</kbd>, but they do work for <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd>, though.

Just for <kbd>Left-Alt</kbd>, I'm forced to have `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` / `WM_SYSKEYUP` messages in my callback.

Is there any option for me to recieve <kbd>Left-Alt</kbd> key events as `WM_KEYDOWN` message instead of `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`?

I already searched Microsoft's docs but found nothing.

Comment: Games typically don't rely on user32.dll window messages, but use e.g. DirectInput

Comment: We can't tell you where your code goes wrong, unless you [edit] your question,  and present a [mcve] as required here, sorry.

Comment: Kinda hard to keep on top of Microsoft's input API Whac-A-Mole game. [DirectInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee416842(v=vs.85)) used to be hot, back when my skin was smooth and my hair hadn't decided to turn grey. It got superseded by [XInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xinput/xinput-game-controller-apis-portal), which, later, got superseded by [GameInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/input/overviews/input-overview). Not sure why all those APIs emerged when we've had Raw Input all along.

Comment: @IInspectable Creating new APIs is what you do when you're out of genuine ideas :/